# Firebird: Adding Index in Create Table Statement

Tags: indexing, firebird, create-table

I've serach the many websites about firebird, but couldn't find an answer to my question.

I'm using ado .net for creating a table in firebird.
And I want to create an index for one of the fields while creating the table:

```
Fbsql = "CREATE TABLE TEST( " +
        "TEST_ID Integer NOT NULL, " +
        "DESCRIPTION Varchar(15), " +
        "PRIMARY KEY (TEST_ID) " + 
        "USING DESCENDING INDEX IDX_DESC ON TEST (DESCRIPTION)); ";
```

But this code doesn't work, I get an "Token unknown" error on the word "on".
What would be the right way to do this if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this doesn't work. If you want to create an index, you need to do that in a separate `create index` statement.

The only indexes that can be created in a `create table` are those created automatically for primary, unique and foreign keys.

The `using`-clause in your question is to control the creation of the index (mainly name) backing one of those keys. It can't be used to create additional indexes.

Comment: Hi Mark, 

That explains why I couldn't find anything online.
Thank you (again) for helping me out.